# How can I perform Optical Character Recognition and have it read with Text-To-Speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, ocr

I know about the (Danish) app SkanRead, but apparently it is discontinued, so I'm looking for alternatives.

The only function I need is that it should allow using the camera to take a photo of some text, and then (some kind of) text-to-speech is used to read the text.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two apps which correspond with your wishes: [Scanthing OCR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scanthing.android) explicitly announces your request (OCR with TTS)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfOuP.jpg)</sup>, and also [Google Goggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf7Cb.jpg)</sup> seems to support it:

[image: Scanthing] [image: Google Goggles]

While the former wants to be paid (~EUR 4) but fully supports what you want, the latter is free -- but I'm not sure whether it reads text via TTS.